Notification Request Appearing Once Only,Flutter

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  noticationcheck();
}

void noticationcheck() async {
  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  settings = await messaging.getNotificationSettings();
  if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
    notfication_message = "ON";
  } else {
    notfication_message = "OFF";
  }
  setState(() {});
}

GestureDetector(
  onTap: () async {
    FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
    NotificationSettings settings =
        await messaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );

    if (settings.authorizationStatus ==
        AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text('Notifications are enabled.'),
          action: SnackBarAction(
            label: 'Go to Settings',
            onPressed: () {
              AppSettings.openAppSettings();
            },
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text('Notifications are disabled.'),
          action: SnackBarAction(
            label: 'Go to Settings',
            onPressed: () {
              AppSettings.openAppSettings();
            },
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    setState(() {});
  },
)

hello i am trying to implement a notification button to enable or disable the application notification.  i am also displaying a text to showcase the settings state ,
firstly in the initstate i check if it is enabeled or not :
my problem is if i tap on allow or don't allow it won't show up again on tap which is why i am putting a snackbar to let the user go to settings to do it .
is there any fix to it or a better way to do it ?

anyone? would really appreciate it
